# Splitting text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner with Python and would appreciate some help. I'm having trouble with the code below as I can't split a file. In my text file I have Gem11 and Gem12 on separate lines and would like to know how to display it in Python in the same format without the quotation marks.

```
with open ("testpractice01.txt" , "r") as f: 
    f_contents = f.readlines()
    print (f_contents)
    f.close()
```

Here's what python is generating. I'm trying to remove the quotation marks etc so I simply have Gem11 and Gem12 so I can then place these in a variable to search through later:

```
['Gem11\n', 'Gem12\n']
```

Comment: Quotation marks are how python demarcates strings. The actual object string does not contain the quotations marks. Now if you want to know how to remove the \n, those are trailing newlines you can remove by calling `str.strip()`

Comment: Do you want to use 'Gem11', 'Gem12' as strings or as a variable?

Comment: @Sunj You cannot expect me to know without seeing the error, or your code. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotation marks are how python demarcates strings. The actual object string does not contain the quotations marks. Try printing each string with `print` and you'll see those quotes disappear.

The other thing to note is the trailing newline in your lines, because file lines are read in with the trailing newline by default, so you'll need to call `str.strip()` to get rid of it. I'd recommend iterating over `f`, the file object, so doing this becomes easier.

```
f_contents = []
with open ("testpractice01.txt" , "r") as f: 
    for line in f:
        f_contents.append(line.strip())

for line in f_contents:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using readlines, use readline.

```
with open ("test.txt" , "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print (line)
    f.close()
```